# How can I create dynamic sized Fields in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I found a way to compose several `intField` (for example) into something that looks like `Field m [Int]`
The function signature is:

```
multiplyField :: Monad m => (RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage, Show a)
              => Field m a -> Field m [a]
```

Of course, this can work fine (except for those multiselect stuff)

The parser works in acceptable way.
But the fieldView is horrible:

```
fieldView = \theId name attrs vals isReq -> do
                    let views = map (\val -> view1 theId name attrs val isReq) $ sequenceA vals
                    [whamlet|$forall view <- views
                               ^{view}
                            |]
```

The problem is that the whole error for several fields in collapsed into only one val (`Left Text [a]`)

This solution works fine if the user always introduce the right data, but if there is an error, all the fields disappear but one.

I don't get why the parser supports n values `[Text]` but the view no.

How can I get something like `[Left Text a]` instead of that `Left Text [a]`?

Comment: Please do not recommend the Yesod book, the solution there is very ad-hoc for passwords or values that disappear: eResult is an unused value.

Comment: This problem seems to affect the standard multi* checkbox* functions, one error blank the whole field.